# Excel VBA bug - (Worksheet_Change) Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, forms, ms-office

I have followed this YT video to make a VBA form in Excel spreadsheet (xlsm): https://youtu.be/SnA3cct-2IM

---

```
Option Explicit
```

At the end of the tutorial after adding the lower code (used to allow editing existing contacts via the form)  to the worksheet, when I fill only name or any other field to save a new contact it does save, but gives an error highlighting the 3rd line (with the comment):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4:D42")) Is Nothing And Range("B4").Value = False And Range("B3").Value = False Then
    Cells(Range("B2").Value, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 21).Value).Value = Target.Value 'THE COMMENT
End If
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA, so the code below is just the rest of the worksheet code:

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C56:J99999")) Is Nothing And Range("C" & Target.Row).Value <> Empty Then
    Range("B2").Value = Target.Row
    Cont_Load
End If
End Sub
```

I also have a module with macros code. I'll add it here if it's necessary

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 21).Value` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: my guess is that you want `Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 21).Value = Target.Value 'THE COMMENT`

Comment: @BigBen what do you mean by "Immediate Window"?

Comment: Use Ctrl+G to bring it up from within the VB Editor.

Comment: @ScottCraner I guessed you meant to remove extra .Value , but it causes compile error.

Comment: No, I meant to replace the whole line with `Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 21).Value = Target.Value 'THE COMMENT`

Comment: @BigBen "Run-time error '424': Object Required"

Comment: @ScottCraner the error disappeared, but now when I want to edit a record from a form - it doesn't update the values in the table.

Comment: Then you will need to debug and walk through line by line to see where it fails.

Comment: @ScottCraner when I debug my original code it ends (bugs?) exactly starting from the 3rd line (the comment line).

Comment: with the new code you will need to put a stop point in the code then you can walk through line by line then you can test if each of your conditions in the IF are returning what you think they should.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. It was because B2 in Worksheet_Change did not have any value.
You have to add
`Range("B2").Value = ContRow`
after
`.Cells(ContRow, ContCol).Value = .Range(.Cells(53, ContCol).Value).Value`      in Cont_Save() (one of the macro functions in the video)